# Using Padrino with Sequel, Can Migrations Create Singularly Named SQL Tables?

Tags: ruby, sequel, padrino, sequel-gem

I'm looking to build an application using the [Padrino Framework](http://www.padrinorb.com/) with [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) as my ORM. The problem is that I need to interface with an existing database which was created using singularly named tables. Rather than renaming the SQL tables (as other applications also use this database), would I be able to have padrino use a singular name for tables (such as "Entry" instead of "Entries")?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a Sequel model on a table with a singular/arbitrary name like this:

`class Entry < Sequel::Model(:entry); end`

Tried this myself in Padrino with an "Entry" table (PostgreSQL) and it works:-

```
$ padrino c

> e = Entry.new
 => #<Entry @values={}> 
> e.save
 => #<Entry @values={:id=>1}> 
> Entry.count
 => 1
```

Inspiration from this question on the [Sequel-Talk Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sequel-talk/Ki3T0bfBEkQ)